Highcharts with Angular loads blank before data is received
I'm trying to integrate Highcharts into my Angular application. I am trying to pull data from the Spring backend and put it in the chart.
I tried using the Angular Highchart tags originally but couldn't get it to work.
The chart wants to load before the data is received so it just shows up as blank:
let testData1;
this.tMService.getCountByHeader().toPromise().then((res: any[]) => {
  testData1 = res;
  this.pieChartOptions1 = {
    series: [{
      type: "pie",
      data: testData1
    }, ],
  };
  this.pieChart1.chart('piechart', this.pieChartOptions1);
})

// Service:

  getCountByHeader(): Observable < any > {
    return this.https.get(`${environment.apiUrl}trainingMetrics/getCountByHeader`)
  }

<mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-card style="height: 82%; width: 100%; margin-top: 2.5em;">
    <mat-card-content>
      <div id='piechart'></div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>


Do you use the Highcharts' official integration for Angular in your project? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Yes I am using that

From what I can see you are not using the highcharts-angular to create the chart. You have a div with piechart id which you use to create the chart when needed.
I believe that you are creating the chart somewhere else because I was not able to recreate that. See how I did that in the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-from-a-service-7jthps
No blank chart is visible
